# How do you open a file using a string from an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I have an array of file names that I need to open. When I put in the plans.open. It gives me the error "no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream::open(std::__cxx11:..."

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream files;
    ifstream plans;
    string stufiles[100];
    int numFiles,timeBlocks;
    files.open("filesToProcess.txt");
    if (files.fail()){ //checks to see if the selected store file opened
        cout << "Error when opening file!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    files >> numFiles;
    for (int i= 0; i<= numFiles; i++) {
         files >> stufiles[i];
    }
    files.close();
    cout << stufiles[0] << endl;
    plans.open(stufiles[0]);
    if (plans.fail()){ //checks to see if the selected store file opened
        cout << "Error when opening file!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is supposed to open the file using the file name in the array.
It gives me the error "no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream::open(std::__cxx11:..."

Comment: `plans.open(stufiles[0].c_str());`

Comment: `for (int i= 0; i<= numFiles; i++) { files >> stufiles[i];` -- Memory overwrite when `i == numFiles`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Only if `numFiles >= 100`

Comment: The loop should be using `<` instead of `<=`

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler's version of `std::ifstream::open()` does not support `std::string` as input, so you will have to give it a `const char*` instead.  You can use `std::string::c_str()` for that:

```cpp
plans.open(stufiles[0].c_str());
```

Comment: I have now changed it to what yous said and now my code compiles and runs; however, now when I do run it the file fails to open. The files are in the same directory.

Comment: @CurtFitz did you verify that `numFiles` is > 0? Did you verify that `stufiles[0]` contains what you are expecting? If you are opening files using relative paths, did you verify that your program's working directory is what you are expecting? These are basic debugging steps.